# How to activate a Jaalee IB002M beacon

Tags: ios, beacon

I've bought 2 Jaalee IB002M Beacons at [BeaconZone](https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/ankhmaway/iB002M) and can't activate them. I've downloaded the Jaalee app from [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/jaalee/id751225894?mt=8) onto my iPad Pro. I have the choice of adding 'Jaalee', 'Jaalee 1S' or 'Jaalee 2' beacons. I've tried all three with the following procedure:

1. Choose the beacon type ('Jaalee', 'Jaalee 1S' or 'Jaalee 2').
2. Press the center button for > 5 seconds until I hear a beep.
3. Release the button an hold the Beacon close to the iPad.

With all three choices nothing happens at all.

I've also installed the 'BLE Scanner' from [ITunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ble-scanner-4-0/id1221763603?mt=8). It does see the 2 beacons and I can connect to them. Sometimes I even get a warning beep back from them.

Is it a bug in the Jaalee App or am I still doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the beacons in an other other app, I would say that this is a bug in the JAALEE app. Apple iOS recognises only beacons advertising the Bluetooth Apple Company Identifier (0x004C) as beacons, but this is usually no problem, because nearly all beacons advertise as such. It could lead to problems, if your beacon was configured (by somebody else) to use an other Company Identifier and or advertising packet as the one expected by the JAALEE app, e.g. when the beacons where used with an other app. Maybe you can reset the beacons to factory defaults.